# uwsgi with Flask app gives "callable not found or import error"

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I want to serve a basic Flask app in a virtualenv using Python 3 and nginx. I'm getting the error

> Internal Server Error

when I attempt to browse to the page. I also see errors in `/var/log/uwsgi/app/myproj.log` that lead me to believe that the error lies within my uwsgi config file. nginx and uwsgi seem to be communicating just fine.

Here's my directory structure:

```
/srv/http/myproj/
             |----- setup.py
             |----- env/
             |----- myproj/
                       |----- __init__.py
                       |----- myproj.py
/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/
                 |----- myproj.ini
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
                 |----- myproj
```

Here's the error I see in `/var/log/uwsgi/app/myproj.log`:

```
Thu Jun  8 00:00:41 2017 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Thu Jun  8 00:00:41 2017 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Thu Jun  8 00:00:41 2017 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Thu Jun  8 00:00:41 2017 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Thu Jun  8 00:00:41 2017 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 14498)
Thu Jun  8 00:00:41 2017 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 14504, cores: 1)
Thu Jun  8 00:00:41 2017 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 14505, cores: 1)
Thu Jun  8 00:00:43 2017 - --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 14505|app: -1|req: -1/1] 172.16.72.2 () {46 vars in 726 bytes} [Thu Jun  8 00:00:43 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Here's `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myproj.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python3
venv = /srv/http/myproj/env
chdir = /srv/http/myproj
module = myproj:myproj
callable = app
```

I also tried with `module` set to `myproj` (which made no change in the uwsgi logs) and `myproj.myproj` (which was less successful because it couldn't find the module `myproj.myproj`).

Here's `/srv/http/myproj/myproj/myproj.py`:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
```

Here's `/srv/http/myproj/myproj/__init__.py`:

```
from myproj.myproj import app
```

Here's `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproj`:

```
upstream myproj {
        server unix:///run/uwsgi/app/myproj/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass myproj;
                include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

I suppose my question is simple: What am I doing wrong?

Edit: In case it matters:

```
# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: Can you run the flask app without uwsgi? Then using uwsgi only?

Comment: @Nurzhan Yes, I can run the Flask app without uwsgi and access it just fine via the browser. I'm not exactly sure what you mean about uwsgi only, but when I run `uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsg/apps-available/myproj.ini --socket /run/uwsgi/app/myproj/socket`, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error from nginx because `(13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`.

Comment: You can start the application with uwsgi only to see if the server serves your correctly. I use gunicorn + nginx and when nginx gives out 502 error it usually happens when the gunicorn is not running in the backend. Check if you can start uwsgi correctly.

Comment: uwsgi does indeed start and not end automatically with the command from my previous comment. There are also no apparent errors in the output (it appears to write to STDOUT rather than a log). There don't seem to be any errors, but I am not familiar with the procedure for connecting to the UNIX socket created by uwsgi and requesting an HTTP resource from it manually without a web server to send the HTTP GET on behalf of a client.

I just tried `socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/run/uwsgi/app/myproj/socket` with `GET / HTTP/1.0` and got the error `Broken pipe`

Comment: Maybe not a big help, but try to go through this tutorial - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look, but I think the problem results from the fact that my directory structure differs from most of the tutorials (including the one you just linked). In the one you linked, the main python file containing the app definition is in the same directory as the virtualenv directory. In my setup, it's abstracted by one directory.

Comment: Have you tried ``module = myproj.myproj``. Having a colon in that doesn't look right as should be a module path.

Comment: Yes, but I received an error that it couldn't find the module `myproj.myproj`. You might have missed it, but I included that in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after looking at a similarly structured project. Here's the new file that solved the problem:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python3
venv = /srv/http/myproj/env
chdir = /srv/http/myproj/myproj
pythonpath = ..
module = myproj
callable = app
```

Essentially, I needed my chdir to go one level deeper (and therefore the module one level less deep).

Edit: And finally, to get my imports in my project to work properly, I also needed to add the pythonpath line seen above.

Answer (score 0):

please check that the uwsgi process has read access for wsgi.py